# Ao carregar site pula para o meio

Tags: javascript, html

Bom essa é minha primeira pergunta aqui, criei uma conta no stackoverflow apenas para isso pois não acho resposta em lugar nenhum!

Acabei de renovar essa página http://www.acm.esy.es/ que está hospedada na hostinger em um plano gratuito! Ao ser carregado ele pula para o fim do site ou para o meio! Já fiz várias otimizações de performance mas o erro continua acontecendo! Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é o atributo `autofocus` no campo:

```
<input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" required autofocus>
```

Quando a página é carregada, o `input` automaticamente ganha `focus`, rolando a página até o local onde ele está na página

Para resolver isso, basta retirar:

```
<input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" required>
```